# Data is not being fetched from mongo database.receiving an empty error.Although collection is present in mongo cloud

Tags: node.js, json, api, post, backend

I am not able to receive data through my get Request. It is returning an empty array although when i check in Mongo Cloud server,it has all the collection.I am using the same flow and code for another collection 'USERS' of same DB and that is working fine.can anyone point out the mistake.
I have provided the Router=>model=>connection files.
[enter image description here][1]connection.js

````
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)

const url = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})


let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
}, { collection: 'users' });


let exerciseSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
}, { collection: 'exercises' });


var collection = {}

collection.getUser = () => {
    return mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then((database) => {
            return database.model('users', userSchema)
        }).catch((err) => {
            return (err + 'Connection couln\'t be established to user database')
        })
}

collection.getExercise = () => {
    return mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then((database) => {

            return database.model('exercises', exerciseSchema)
        }).catch((err) => {
            return (err + 'Connection couln\'t be established to exercise database')
        })
}
module.exports = collection;```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moT2z.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use find or findOne query

```
return database.model(...).find({}).exec();
```

For more info https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html